# Image compression using Lossy Compression technique

Tags: matlab, image-processing, jpeg, jpeg2000, lossy-compression

I need to convert PNG to JPEG,JPEG 2000 using ImageMagick and Matlab. I want to compress all data with ratio ( e.g. 10) and then specify some file size? Any idea or solution to achieve the specific file size? How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagemagick can create a JPG of your desired file size. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#jpg

```
-define jpeg:extent={size}
As of IM v6.5.8-2 you can specify a maximum output filesize for the JPEG image. The size is specified with a suffix. For example "400kb".
```